# Git is monitoring a bad folder location

Tags: git, visual-studio

I'm using git with the visual studio when trying to sync with my git repo, there are too many and unnecessary changes, I only want to push the local files in my project,
[image]

315k changes, my project contains just a few.

this is my default repo location:
[image]

this is the output of the source control - git
[image]

thanks for the help.

Comment: It looks like you created a Git repo directly in your user directory? You want it in a specific project directory.

Comment: Hi, this is my default repo location
c:\users\shaio\Source\Repos

Comment: Sure, but that's a Visual Studio seeing where to store project files. Git is not Visual Studio. You have created a Git repo in `C:\Users\shaio`, and that is going to track all files and subdirectories from there. Remove the .git directory there and initialize a repo in the directory where you want.

Comment: It sounds like an EOL format change. Check eith `git diff`.. Do files look as completely cleared up and replaced with the same (or almost) content? Then it's an EOL format change.

Comment: Exactly what CodeCaster said. Look at the first line of the tree of changes. It looks at c:\users\shaio and then first entry is c:\users\shaio\.jenkins\workspace. It is outside c:\users\shaio\Source\Repos and that means that the .git folder is too high in the folder hierarchy

Comment: @eftshift0 what do you mean? there's no such thing on the screenshot attached to the post. It's all ADDED, git sees them as new files, no indication of any eol flips

Comment: when looking in C:\Users\shaio I have Source folder, inside a Repo folder, but inside it, I have all my Repos in git, I don't want to delete them, I want to be able to use again but in the correct way of using.

Comment: Don't delete them! Check if you have `c:\users\shaio\.git` folder and report back :)

Comment: I don't have .git folder in the path c:\users\shaio

Comment: Or you don't see it, because it's hidden.

Comment: I can see many folders with .X name but not .git

Comment: I have edited my post and added a new picture

Comment: Instead of trying to prove me wrong, try and assume I'm right. The .git folder is hidden. Explorer by default doesn't show hidden folders.

Comment: @CodeCaster I'm sorry, I just enabled the view of hidden folders, and the .git appeared in the path you said.
I thought that the .X is a hidden file and thus I assumed that I should have found it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have initialized a Git repository a few directories up too high, in `C:\Users\shaio`. This will add all files and directories from there. You probably don't want that, so make sure your Explorer shows hidden files and remove the `.git` directory from there.

Then initialize the Git repository in the directory of your solution file.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, I did learn a lot by this mistake that i made. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you go to repository settings, there is an option to edit so called .gitignore file (can even be found in project directory and edited in any other text editor). In this file, you specify folders and file extensions which are not added to git commits.

Official git documentation for gitignore [there](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).

Comment: While in general this is the way to have files you don't want in Git not show up, the problem here is different, look at the paths in the screenshot.